# How to extend Auth0's middleware?

Tags: express, auth0

I'm trying to add some properties to the results of the authentication process. Auth0 sets up Express middleware like this:

```
  export const checkJwt = auth({
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
    issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUERBASEURL,
  });
```

This checks the authorisation header and works fine. It creates an request.auth object and adds payload into that. Works.

However, I want to add details from my own database, such as an ID or an organisation the user belongs to.

I've tried multiple ways to capture the result of auth but just can't get my head around it.

```
export var newAuth = function (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {

  const opts = {
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
    issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUERBASEURL,
  };

  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    // is the issue here?
    var result = auth(opts)(req, res, next);

    return result;
  }
};
```

I suppose I'm asking how can I intercept or extend middleware in Express?

Comment: Did you refer these -> [express-oauth2-bearer](https://github.com/auth0/express-oauth2-bearer) **and** [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)

Comment: Yes, the Auth middleware is from express-auth2-bearer